# Finish command from history

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, iterm2, key-binding

A couple of years ago I enabled "finish text" command on iTerm2 + ZSH. For example, if I had "git commit" in my command history in a new command window if I typed "gi" "t history" would be viewable but slightly transparent and I could press right arrow on keyboard to finish command. I forget how I enabled this and have been searching how to enable but cannot find the method.

How to enable "finish command based on history" by pressing right arrow on iterm2 + zsh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed
[zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions).

To use it, add the following to `~/.zshrc` :

```
antibody bundle zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
```